# Apache JMeter : How to compare responses of same HTML request during loop?

Tags: apache, jmeter

Please reply me with the solution for following problem:

With Apache JMeter I have ran the 2000 requests per 2 minutes with 10 loops.
The request is for checking hotel availability for mentioned start and end dates. 
Following 3 important parameters are there:
Hotel id, Start date and End date
With the help of 'CSV data set Config' I have stored input from 2 text files (1 text file has hotel ids and another having start,End dates). and used variables into http requests.

By taking listeners View Result Tree and summary report, I checked the responses of each request. For some requests I am getting blank responses, as hotel is not available. Now I want to find out the exact count of the blank responses. Please let me know if anybody has solution for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use i.e. [Size Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Size_Assertion) or [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to mark blank requests as failed ones.

If you just need just number and don't want to record failures on blank responses I would suggest using a Beanshell Post processor as follows.

1. Define a User Defined Variable called i.e. `blank` with the value of `0`
2. Add a Beanshell Post Processor to each request which may produce blank response
3. At the end add a Beanshell Sampler which will report the final variable

Example Post Processor code:

```
int blank = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("blank")); //get current "blank" variable value
String response = new String(data); //get response data as string

if (response.length() == 0) // if response length equals zero (feel free to update this as requred)
{
    blank++; // increment "blank" variable
}

vars.put("blank", String.valueOf(blank)); // update "blank" variable value
```

Example final Beanshell sampler code:

```
log.info("Pages with blank response count: " + vars.get("blank")); // print current "blank" variable value to "jmeter.log" file
```

You should see something like below in jmeter.log file:

> 2014/05/15 18:36:34 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: **Pages
>   with blank response count: 15**
>   2014/05/15 18:36:34 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
>   2014/05/15 18:36:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine:
>   Notifying test listeners of end of test
>   2014/05/15 18:36:34 INFO  -
>   jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for JMeter extension with scripting walkthrough and a kind of Beanshell cookbook.